# "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column" Angular with Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, angularjs, angular

I am trying some code related to Angular with Visualforce. Here I am trying to implement modal in https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Now when I use a templateURL and give a new apex as url, then I get the error mentioned in subject.

Code snippet for angular template -

```
$scope.open = function() {
           var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: '/apex/newProjectForm',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
              items: function () {
                return $scope.list5;
              }
            }
          });

           modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            console.log('2-->', $scope.user);

          }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
          });
      }
```

For the newProjectForm.apge -

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="NewProjectController">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
    </style>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!projectInstance.Name}"></apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!projectInstance.Start_Date__c}"></apex:inputField>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

I understand somehow angular is not able to understand the colon : in "apex:inputfield", but not sure that how I can solve it.

**Update 1**
ok, I checked again and I cannot find mark up of modal in page. not sure how angular loads it internally

**Update 2**
The actual only seems to be because of Salesforce way to putting id to elements. so I gave Ids to apex:page as well as apex:form so the error that I am getting is -

> Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 13 of the
>   expression [completePage:completeForm] starting at [:completeForm].

Where "completePage" is id of page and "completeForm" is the id of form.

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: I assume that the content that arrives in the browser will have had the Visualforce tags replaced by HTML. (Use your browser's "View Source" on any Visualforce page and you will see the big changes applied by Visualforce.) Your page has no Angular markup in it so this is a strange mix you are using.

Comment: The VF page that I have added is just the page that should get open in template, if you need I can add snippets of the main page as well

Comment: @KeithC , I checked the source and added Update 1 in description.

Comment: Changed again..

Comment: Have you tried to give ids to the elements?

Comment: Yes , I gave ids to both form and page, but I feel the issue is with SF way of rendering ids to elements like - pageId:formid and angular library not able to understand :formId portion

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem caused by AngularJS using jQuery and appears to be a known limitation (see [issue 13771](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13771)); jQuery treats colons as special selectors so ids with colons break the parser. Your options are to either override the form directive or move the `apex:form` tag outside of your Angular app, which is what I did.

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved it is to use a built in Angular directive that tells Angular to not parse that element.

The directive is called `ng-non-bindable`. You can put it on any element that you do not want parsed.

```
<apex:form html-ng-non-bindable="true" id="theForm">
```