# Create a modal with angular and VF

Tags: visualforce, javascript, angularjs, angular

I want to create a modal window where I can use input fields etc but all these should be in a modal like https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

I am currently facing issue same as ["Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column" Angular with Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97907/error-parsesyntax-syntax-error-token-is-an-unexpected-token-at-column)

Is there a way by which we can use standard angular modal with SF input fields and then how can I control the pop up completion.

Thanks,

Ray